# SQLAlchemy onupdate keyword doesn't trigger in joined tables

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

I have the following class structure:

```
class A(Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    text = Column(String(255))
    time_updated = Column(DateTime, onupdate=func.now())
    type = Column(String(50))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'a',
        'polymorphic_on': type
    }


class B(A):
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('a.id'), primary_key=True)
    more_text = Column(String(255))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'b',
        'inherit_condition': (id == a.id),
    }
```

If I update an instance of `B` by changing the value of `more_text` `onupdate` is not triggered and `time_updated` doesn't change - which makes sense, as table B is not touched. But this is not what I want. How can I get SQLAlchemy to trigger onupdate for *all* changes to the instance?

I tried using an event listener for the `before_update` event, but this only works if I define it for the class B. As there will be many more classes extending A this is not a clean option. Is there any better way?